# draw horizontal line in primeFaces chart

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts, jqplot, horizontal-line

i am trying to draw horizontal line for show max and min trend in my primeFaces line chart but cannot understand ho to do there is my xhtml code:

```
          <div align="center">
                                <p:outputPanel id="fuelAnalysisPanel">

  <p:chart type="line" model="#{generatorDataLogReportBean.animatedModel2}" style="width:95%;"  widgetVar="fuelChart"/>
                                    <br/>

                                </p:outputPanel>
                            </div>
```

and my java class code is:

```
 private void createAnimatedModelsForFuel(ArrayList<Param> dataLog) {
        animatedModel2 = initLinearModelForFuel(dataLog);
        animatedModel2.setTitle("Fuel Graph (%)");
        animatedModel2.setAnimate(true);
        animatedModel2.setLegendPosition("se");

        animatedModel2.setSeriesColors("D42F36");
        Axis yAxis = animatedModel2.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
        yAxis.setMin(0);
        yAxis.setMax(100);
        yAxis.setLabel("Percentage %");

    }

    private LineChartModel initLinearModelForFuel(ArrayList<Param> dataLog) {
        LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();

        LineChartSeries series1 = new LineChartSeries();
        series1.setLabel("Fuel%");
        int i = 1;
        String dt = "";
        //int size = dataLog.size()-1 ;

        /*        for (; size >= 0; size--) {                        
         if (dataLog.get(size) instanceof VT12Param) {



         series1.set(i++, ((VT12Param) dataLog.get(size)).getActualFuelPercent());

         } 
         }
         */
        for (Param p : dataLog) {
            if (p instanceof VT12Param) {
                dt = sdf2.format(((VT12Param) p).getDateTime().getTime());
                series1.set(dt, ((VT12Param) p).getActualFuelPercent());

            } else if (p instanceof T20Param) {
                dt = sdf2.format(((T20Param) p).getDateTime().getTime());
                series1.set(dt, ((T20Param) p).getActualFuelPercent());

            }
        }

        //model.setDatatipFormat("%s, %s");
        model.addSeries(series1);

        DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Dates");

        axis.setTickAngle(-30);
        model.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);

        //axis.setMax(sdf.format(toDate.getTime()));
        axis.setTickFormat("%b %#d, %H:%M"); //%b %#d, %#I %p // %b %#d, %#I:%M %p

        if(dataLog.size() < 500){
                 axis.setTickInterval(dataLog.size()+"00000");
            }
            else{
            axis.setTickInterval(dataLog.size()+"0000");
            }

        model.setLegendCols(15);
        model.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
        // model.setZoom(true);

        return model;
    }
```

and i want horizontal line like this these blue lines:
[image]

Comment: You tryed create a new `LineChartSeries` to draw the line? One serie to max, other to min, and other to your data.